# boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int) - templated class member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, boost

I was looking for any tips, how to make code below to work and I couldn't find anything. So I wonder if this is even possible...

I need to run a few threads inside my parametrized class. Here is a sample code:

```
template<typename T, int SIZE, class ThreadingSettings, class CheckingPolicy>
class MyClass {
  void Run() { boost::thread testThread(WriteValueA, 5); }
  void WriteValueA(const T value) {/* some work here */}
}
```

But g++ errors:

```
boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)
```

And this is how I create an object of that class:

```
typedef MyClass<int, 4, SingleThread, NoCheckingPolicy> int_class;
int_class a;
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm using NetBeans with cygwin on Win7. I include following files:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one `WriteValueA` function? Do you have any free function `WriteValueA` any `static`?

Comment: Have you tried `boost::thread testThread(&MyClass::WriteValueA, this, 5);`?

Comment: @ildjarn your code gives me `undefined reference to 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I don't know what free function means, but there is only one WriteValueA function :) And it isn't static, however there is pointer to static array in this function...

Comment: @HermeZ : That sounds like a problem with your build of Boost.Thread. How did you build it?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T, int SIZE, class ThreadingSettings, class CheckingPolicy>
class MyClass {
public:
  void Run() { boost::thread testThread(boost::ref(*this), 5); }
  void operator()(const T value) {/* some work here */}
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get `undefined reference to 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'` and what is more important there is WriteValueB (it's similar to WriteValueA) and I need them both (one thread for each function), so I can't use operator()

Comment: the problem is in your boost libs/linking